# Looking for the source of this quote I copied in Dec 1987

Tags: story-identification

The copied quote is:

> 12-2-87
>
> "Forty thousand legions walked across the desert of the moon in search of the land of Narda. The fly space was crowded by their cars and travel logs. The sun rose in the East as the terminator marched over the dusty air-less surface pockmarked by the cosmic acne of space.
>
> They circle and fly in endless orbits while the gentle dawning of the world comes over the horizon unseen and timid. One by one they awake to the beauty and tranquility of the dawn--no more does night flash into day but creeps sweetly into being.
>
> Restless they stir and open wide their senses to the era of love that speaks the language of the soul. Desolate has been vanquished and light has awakened their long quiet souls to beauty. I hear without words, the emptiness of space is full of the sounds of the awakening."

[Full scan of text as written above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scA17.jpg)

I'm assuming it is from a scifi or fantasy work, but not sure.

Comment: The obvious [Tales of Narda](https://www.talesofnarda.com/) fantasy doesn't seem to fit - no cars and a decade and a half too late.

Comment: The meaning of "terminator" in the quote is the moving day-night boundary on a (nearly) airless body like the moon.  With too tenuous an atmosphere to scatter much light, the boundary appears quite sharp (just like shadows on the moon are very dark).

Comment: Is there any other *potential* evidence on the paper you wrote this quote on? Other notes, something cryptic, initials, names --- anything? A hi res scan of your original document would be helpful.

Comment: The style reminds me of the Warhammer books. Possibly something associated with a game of that genre?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind transcribing the rest...

Comment: You've got a date of "12-2-87" in the typed transcription, but it looks more like 12-5-87 in the handwritten original.

Comment: If you don't recall its source, what makes you think it was a quote at all and not simply your own composition? Was manually copying long SF passages something you specifically remember doing?

Comment: Jacob, good question, but it doesn't read like my writing style. Guess I'll never know.